# In "Castle in the Sky", do the grown men on board of the pirate ship want to date the little girl?

Tags: castle-in-the-sky

I just watched this movie for the first time. One thing I didn't quite understand.

As soon as Sheeta joins the pirates, walking with the "mother" pirate, all the crew members (who seem like adults) clearly check her out, and later all extremely eagerly want to help her out in the kitchen (to be near her). They seem to be very much in love with her. All of them.

Is this correctly interpreted? I just found it kind of odd that a bunch of pirate men who seem 30+ all are so interested in that little girl who looks like she's 9 or something.

Comment: She's 13, not that that improves things much. I've read that in the Japanese they see her more as a mother figure rather than a romantic figure. But yeah, super creepy.

Comment: The brothers are [30,25,20 yo](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%8E%E3%83%A9%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF#%E7%A9%BA%E4%B8%AD%E6%B5%B7%E8%B3%8A%E3%80%8C%E3%83%89%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E4%B8%80%E5%AE%B6%E3%80%8D). Well, it does look weird but it is correct to interpret them in love with Sheeta (By the way, [the name derived from Θ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%8E%E3%83%A9%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF#%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%E7%94%B1%E6%9D%A5)).